# Is it possible to send and receive a file from ubuntu to windows without apps like samba etc?

Tags: files, samba, ftp, transfer

Most of the suggestions and queries are showing samba and other application installations. It needs to be done programatically without any third-party client or servers.

Comment: If you use ftp as a tag you do understand you can do this with ftp? ;-) Other options are ssh, telnet. Lots of people use "winscp" on Windows. You will need to install something though; either on Windows or on Ubuntu.

Comment: This is too vague. Please edit your question to explain what you are trying to do, and why you can't use something like Samba.

Comment: Do you want to do it programatically, or is it a one-time thing?

Answer (score 1):

I have found WinSCP to be the best tool for a Windows desktop or server interacting with a Linux environment.

You need to install ssh on the Linux environment first for WinSCP to work.